Retagging Questions about Derivatives, Integration, ODEs, etc. with the Calculus Tag
Whenever I encounter a question about integration, ODEs, derivatives, etc. which are tagged correctly with integration, indefinite-integrals, definite-integrals, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, etc. but not calculus, should I retag them with calculus or not and why? The answer seems to be no as per a highly upvoted comment on my previous question, but I would like to know the reason. And if the answer is no,

What is the exact purpose of the calculus tag?
Should I remove the calculus tag from the questions about integration, ODEs, derivatives, etc. that use it?


My personal opinion:
Don't add retag with calculus questions that already have a tag like derivatives that makes it clear that calculus is involved.
Don't remove the calculus tag from questions that already use it. It's not hurting anybody.
Don't sweat the small stuff. Leave well enough alone. There are more valuable contributions you can make to the website.
[Ordinarily, I would leave the above as a comment, but an answer has the advantage that other users can vote it up or down, as they see fit, whereas comments can only be voted up.]
